# Why doesn't Stripe PHP library set the params as an array and do that check inside the function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I was checking the [Stripe PHP library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) and I notice that they don't do something like this:

```
function($params=array())
```

but do

```
function($params=null)
```

and inside the function

```
if(!$params): $params = array();
```

Here is an example of what I am talking about: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Stripe/Customer.php#L108

My question, why don't they do

```
function($params=array())
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Sounds like a question to ask them.

Comment: I thought it was some PHP practice I ignore.

Comment: If you work with other people's code, you'll find tons of examples of ways to make their code more concise, readable, efficient, etc. If you've spotted this example, you could probably spot dozens, if not hundreds more. Seriously, coders with your mindset are always welcome on any project I'm involved with. Not only are you thinking about efficiency and conciseness but you're approaching it with humility, asking "Is there any valid reason for doing this?" I can't answer your question here but I can encourage you to keep coding, because I wish more coders had your mindset.

Comment: @cazort Thank you for your kind words!